# how to calculate weighted median by groups

Tags: r, dplyr, median, weighted

I need to calculate a weighted median age by 3 variables (gender, sector and occupation). I know how to use "spatstat" weighted.median. But it gives the weighted age of the entire DF. I don't know hot to make it calculate it by groups/variables. I found another similar post from 2 years ago but i did not understand the solution offered in it. I did understand that you would need to use dplyr to group it. I have very limited understanding of the library. I would need someone to show me the code for the following DF so i can use it and do small changes to it if needed in the future.

My DF is as follows: The original df is much larger and has many more sectors and occupations. But the structure is the same.

```
 
Gender    Sector     occupation     Age     Weight
  M         A            1          45      13.12
  F         C            1          23       7.05
  M         A            3          67      34.12
  M         A            3          23      11.00
  F         C            1          33      17.45
  F         A            1          35      45.01
  F         C            3          57      21.45
  M         C            1          32      23.33
  F         A            3          48      44.54
  M         A            1          25      13.12
  F         C            1          27       7.05
  M         A            3          37      34.12
  M         A            3          26      11.00
  F         C            1          73      17.45
  F         A            1          49      45.01
  F         C            3          24      21.45
  M         C            1          25      23.33
  F         A            3          35      44.54
  M         A            1          48      13.12
  F         C            1          83       7.05
  M         A            3          66      34.12
  M         A            3          43      11.00
  F         C            1          36      17.45
  F         A            1          35      45.01
  F         C            3          57      21.45
  M         C            1          22      23.33
  F         A            3          47      44.54
  M         A            1          55      13.12
  F         C            1          28       7.05
  M         A            3          27      34.12
  M         A            3          25      11.00
  F         C            1          23      17.45
  F         A            1          46      45.01
  F         C            3          34      21.45
  M         C            1          27      23.33
  F         A            3          65      44.54
```

This is the result I need. NB! The median age in here is fake. It just represents the structure of the end result.

```
Gender    Sector     occupation   Median age
  M         A            1            23
  M         A            3            34
  M         C            1            45
  M         C            3            23
  F         A            1            34
  F         A            3            45
  F         C            1            43
  F         C            3            34
```

The question I found (mentioned above) I did not understand it because i do not understand mutate and the data in the example is presented in a way that i can't read. I'm new to R

[weighted median by_group()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51428684/weighted-median-by-group)

Answer (score 4):

There is a `weighted.median` from `spatstat` package.  We could use that along with `tidyverse` approach i.e. grouped by 'Gender', 'Sector' and 'occupation', apply the `weighted.median` with `x` as 'Age' and `w` as 'Weight' in `summarise`.

In the linked post, it is using `mutate` as it is creating a new column while `summarise` returns the summarised output i.e. one row for each group.

In addition, we should be cautious when using `summarise/mutate` as those functions are found in `plyr` as well and it could mask the `dplyr` functions if both packages are loaded i.e. if the masked function from `plyr` was used, then instead of grouping, it may return the `weighted.median` of the whole data.  So, either load only `dplyr` or use explicitly `dplyr::summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(spatstat)
df1 %>% 
     group_by(Gender, Sector, occupation) %>%
     dplyr::summarise(MedianAge = weighted.median(Age, Weight),
           .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  Gender Sector occupation MedianAge
  <chr>  <chr>       <int>     <dbl>
1 F      A               1      35  
2 F      A               3      47  
3 F      C               1      31.0
4 F      C               3      34  
5 M      A               1      45  
6 M      A               3      33.8
7 M      C               1      25
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Gender = c("M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", 
"M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", 
"M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", 
"F", "M", "F"), Sector = c("A", "C", "A", "A", "C", "A", "C", 
"C", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "C", "A", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", 
"A", "A", "C", "A", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "C", "A", 
"C", "C", "A"), occupation = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L), Age = c(45L, 
23L, 67L, 23L, 33L, 35L, 57L, 32L, 48L, 25L, 27L, 37L, 26L, 73L, 
49L, 24L, 25L, 35L, 48L, 83L, 66L, 43L, 36L, 35L, 57L, 22L, 47L, 
55L, 28L, 27L, 25L, 23L, 46L, 34L, 27L, 65L), Weight = c(13.12, 
7.05, 34.12, 11, 17.45, 45.01, 21.45, 23.33, 44.54, 13.12, 7.05, 
34.12, 11, 17.45, 45.01, 21.45, 23.33, 44.54, 13.12, 7.05, 34.12, 
11, 17.45, 45.01, 21.45, 23.33, 44.54, 13.12, 7.05, 34.12, 11, 
17.45, 45.01, 21.45, 23.33, 44.54)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-36L))
```